# Need T-SQL update statement to dynamically assign a record number

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a data set that I got from XML and have it broken out with the following structure:

**[Data Table]**

```
[ID] [Name]     [Value]
1    ad1_pk     1
2    ad1_addr1  123 Easy Street
3    ad1_pk     2
4    ad1_addr1  99 US31
5    ad1_atfk   6
6    ad1_pk     3
... {and so on}
```

I have added a column (called recNum) to indicate the distinct record number; however, I have not found a quick way to set the record number for each record.  The number of rows that indicate a distinct record can vary, so I want the update statement to be able to handle this.  Each "record" has a "column" name that ends with "_pk", so that's how I'm determining the start of each record in the dataset.

I have done this successfully with a while loop, but it's way too slow and tables can have millions of records.  Example:

```
DECLARE @maxRowID INT = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM myTable)
DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @currentRecordID INT = 1

WHILE @i<@maxRowID AND @i<100 BEGIN
    IF (SELECT RIGHT(name,3) [name] FROM myTable WHERE ID=@i)='_pk' AND @i>1 BEGIN
        SET @currentRecordID = (SELECT DISTINCT value FROM myTable WHERE id=@i)
        RAISERROR('Record=%i',0,1,@currentRecordID) WITH NOWAIT
        UPDATE z2
        SET recNum=@currentRecordID
        FROM myTable z2
        WHERE id=@i
    END ELSE BEGIN
        UPDATE z2
        SET recNum=@currentRecordID
        FROM myTable z2
        WHERE id=@i
    END
    SET @i = @i+1
END
```

Does anybody have a suggestion to do this in a quick manner w/o using a cursor?
My ultimate goal is to insert statements into an SQL table (already created) with the following format:

```
insert into myNewTable ({column name list}) VALUES ({value list})
```

...
[updated 2015-06-24 00:26 EDT]
This is how far I have gotten thus far...
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B82UP-AIFz_ITlNIb1ZwSFdyODg/view?usp=sharing

```
SELECT TOP 100
z2.ID,z2.Name,z2.Value,CASE WHEN z2.ID=RecIDs.ID THEN z2.Value ELSE NULL END RecNum
FROM MyTable 2
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID) drn,ID FROM MyTable
    WHERE RIGHT(name,3)='_pk'
) RecIDs ON RecIDs.ID = z2.ID
ORDER BY ID
```

... I need to fill in the gaps.
Any suggestions?

[updated 2015-06-25 09:33 EDT]
This is for SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: If you really need help, please make it easier for people to help. For reference on how to do that : [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: Your edit does not make the question easier to understand. Please edit your question to include the relevat tables structure and desired result.

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you want to assign a value for `RecNum` for all `PK` using `ROW_NUMBER`. After that, you want to update the remaining rows with the appropriate `RecNum`

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c39b1/1/0)

```
WITH CtePKs AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID)
    FROM z2
    WHERE RIGHT(Name, 3) = '_pk'
)
UPDATE CtePKs SET RecNum = RN 

UPDATE z
    SET RecNum = x.RecNum
FROM z2 z
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 Id, RecNum
    FROM z2
    WHERE
        ID < z.ID 
        AND RecNum IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY ID DESC
)x
WHERE z.RecNum IS NULL
```

**RESULT**

```
| ID |      Name |           Value | RecNum |
|----|-----------|-----------------|--------|
|  1 |    ad1_pk |               1 |      1 |
|  2 | ad1_addr1 | 123 Easy Street |      1 |
|  3 |    ad1_pk |               2 |      2 |
|  4 | ad1_addr1 |         99 US31 |      2 |
|  5 |  ad1_atfk |               6 |      2 |
|  6 |    ad1_pk |               3 |      3 |
```

Comment: How am I supposed to get the value from the CTE to the final update statement, since CTEs are only available once?

Comment: What do you mean? The first `UPDATE` to the `CTE` also updates its reference table.

Comment: Ok, I get the first CTE update statement.  However, now there's a problem I found with the second one, where it's taking way too long to do the update.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use a correlated subquery like this. If you are using SQL Server 2012 or above, you can use `SUM() OVER()` as well. Check Edit.

**Sample Data**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ID] int,rowid int, [Name] varchar(9), [Value] varchar(15));

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ID], [Name], [Value])
VALUES
    (1, 'ad1_pk', '1'),
    (2, 'ad1_addr1', '123 Easy Street'),
    (3, 'ad1_pk', '2'),
    (4, 'ad1_addr1', '99 US31'),
    (5, 'ad1_atfk', '6'),
    (6, 'ad1_pk', '3');
```

**Query**

```
UPDATE Table1
SET rowid = 
 (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table1 T2 WHERE T2.ID <= Table1.ID AND T2.Name Like '%[_]pk');

SELECT * FROM Table1;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ed78/6)**

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID | rowid |      Name |           Value |
|----|-------|-----------|-----------------|
|  1 |     1 |    ad1_pk |               1 |
|  2 |     1 | ad1_addr1 | 123 Easy Street |
|  3 |     2 |    ad1_pk |               2 |
|  4 |     2 | ad1_addr1 |         99 US31 |
|  5 |     2 |  ad1_atfk |               6 |
|  6 |     3 |    ad1_pk |               3 |
```

**EDIT**

For *SQL Server 2012* or above

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Name LIKE '%[_]pk' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY ID) recnum,* 
FROM Table1
  )
  UPDATE CTE
  SET rowid = recnum;

  SELECT * FROM Table1;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ed78/8)**

Comment: formatted your output based on the sql fiddle result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [cte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) for that:

```
;With cte as (
    SELECT [id], Row_number() OVER(Order by [id] As rn
    FROM MyTable
)

UPDATE MyTable
SET recNum = rn
FROM MyTable t
INNER JOIN cte ON(t.[id] = cte.[id])
```

However, you since already have an id column that seems to have the values you are asking for, you can simply do this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET recNum = [id]
```

Comment: This does not do what I want, since I need to add a column to indicate the "record" that exists.  Please review my updates.